# Split characters from a list of tuples?

Tags: python, string, data-structures, escaping

Im new at python and i have the following list of n tuples:

```
[('Mi', 'dp1css'), ('colega', 'nccs000'), ('me', 'pp1cs000'), ('ayuda', 'ncfs000'), ('a', 'sps00'), ('programar', None), ('cosas<', None)]
```

In the second tuple i would like to split or drop from the thirth character to the nth character Could anybody help me with this task (e.g. from the above list, the new list as follows ('Mi', 'dp'))

Comment: `e = [(a,b[2:] if b else None) for a,b in d]` where d is your input variable

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do with the tuples that have `None` as the second element, so I threw them out.

```
>>> l = [('Mi', 'dp1css'), ('colega', 'nccs000'), ('me', 'pp1cs000'), ('ayuda', 'ncfs000'), ('a', 'sps00'), ('programar', None), ('cosas<', None)]
>>> [(i, j[0:2]) for i,j in l if j != None]
[('Mi', 'dp'), ('colega', 'nc'), ('me', 'pp'), ('ayuda', 'nc'), ('a', 'sp')]
```

If you want to keep the `None` elements, you can do this

```
>>> [(i, j[0:2]) if j else (i, None) for i,j in l]
[('Mi', 'dp'), ('colega', 'nc'), ('me', 'pp'), ('ayuda', 'nc'), ('a', 'sp'), ('programar', None), ('cosas<', None)]
```